# No route matches [POST] "/users/1/edit" when updating from form - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise, rails-routing

New to Rails..

I'm accessing a form at: /users/1/edit (which shows but doesn't update and throws error) and I also have a devise form at: /user/edit (which shows and updates correctly)

I'm using Rails 4 and Devise 3.1.

routes.rb:

```
    resources :users
    devise_for :user, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
    get 'users/:id' => 'users#show'
```

and my available paths:

```
users_path                      GET /users(.:format)    users#index
                                POST    /users(.:format)    users#create
new_user_path                   GET /users/new(.:format)    users#new
edit_user_path                  GET /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
user_path                       GET /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
                                PATCH   /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
                                PUT /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
                                DELETE  /users/:id(.:format)    users#destroy

new_user_session_path           GET /user/sign_in(.:format) devise/sessions#new
user_session_path               POST    /user/sign_in(.:format) devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session_path       DELETE  /user/sign_out(.:format)    devise/sessions#destroy
user_password_path              POST    /user/password(.:format)    devise/passwords#create
new_user_password_path          GET /user/password/new(.:format)    devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password_path         GET /user/password/edit(.:format)   devise/passwords#edit
                                PATCH   /user/password(.:format)    devise/passwords#update
                                PUT /user/password(.:format)    devise/passwords#update

cancel_user_registration_path   GET /user/cancel(.:format)  registrations#cancel
user_registration_path          POST    /user(.:format) registrations#create
new_user_registration_path      GET /user/sign_up(.:format) registrations#new
edit_user_registration_path     GET /user/edit(.:format)    registrations#edit
                                PATCH   /user(.:format) registrations#update
                                PUT /user(.:format) registrations#update
                                DELETE  /user(.:format) registrations#destroy
                                GET /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
```

users_controller.rb

```
    def index
     @users = User.all
    end

    def show
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
    end

    def create
     @user = User.create(user_params)
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private

    def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
    end
```

UPDATE:
I figured out an answer for this so removed some of the content.

Comment: show me the registrations controller

Comment: I updated this and I had :description in the account_update_params, but this is for a different form for profile.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by how you setup your application but it might be worth noting that I don't think your form knows what to update.  try this:

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
...
```

Then you need to update your edit action in your User Controller:

```
def edit
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  @profile = user.profile
end
```

*Please note it can sound like Profile is its own class and belongs to the User because your user model states "has_one :profile."  But I don't think that's actually the case and if its not, you should remove that language from your model.  But if it is the case, you'll need to have a profile controller that will have similar CRUD actions which should include the action method I described above.*

Comment: Yea, that didn't fix it. I will go another route and create a Profile controller. Thanks!

Comment: Just added the profile controller and realized that I'm using the users to do the same thing. Profile controller wasn't needed, and you are correct Profile model wasn't doing anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Users` controller needs an `update` action

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def update
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.update(user_params)
  end
end
```

Comment: That change didn't effect anything. Everything works the same as it did before, including the error. Any other ideas?

Comment: are you trying to update the user here or the profile of the user?

Comment: Technically I'm trying to update what is shown on users/1/edit so I can show it on the profile page at: /users/1

Comment: Thanks Ken but your form makes me think you want to edit a Profile.  Are you updating an instance of a `User`here or something else?

Comment: Either way at this point. One is under users and one is under user. Basically 2 forms with one going to devise user and the other to the profile users. If that makes sense. I don't need to update both at once, as the devise form works perfectly but I have too many attributes so I wanted to add the others under the Profile users portion.. like description, age, location, gender and so on.

Comment: Right now I have "description" string under Users in my schema.. along with everything else.